# Python keycodes to break out of a screen terminal session

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been looking online for a way to break out of a screen terminal session.  The keys to break out of a session are:

**Ctrl+A then D**
OR
**Ctrl+A then Ctrl+D**

I've got the Ctrl+A part:

**child.send(b'\x01')**

But cannot find the keycode for Ctrl+D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the ASCII table. It is child.send(b'\x04') (EOT)

Comment: Well... That worked.  Thank you very much for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL/D  is `b'\x04'`. There are many references, of which [this](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) was the first I came across.

Comment: Thank you very much - Especially for the reference - Now I understand it.